# My dataframe is taking first row of dataset as index of the dataset.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I opened the .log file in dataframe (python). But the first row of dataset is taken as name of the columns. I tried to change the name of columns. But it deleted the first row. Need solutions.

Comment: Fascinating story. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You need parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = df.read_csv('filename.csv', names = ['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""1,1,a
1,2,b
2,1,c
3,1,d"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), names=['col1','col2','col3'])
print (df)
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     1    a
1     1     2    b
2     2     1    c
3     3     1    d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "header=None" option with the read_csv method.  That will create a column index for you.  If you need column names, do as in the answer from @jezrael.

```
pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=None)
```